# How much data does a game use?

Tags: dota-2

I currently play DotA 2 and in the summer my Internet will be capped at 5GB/month. On average how much data does a game of DotA 2 use?

Answer (score 8):

Take care that Dota 2 traffic is not the only thing you should take into account. There are weekly Dota 2 patches (200-500MB), there are Steam patches and Steam traffic.

But speaking about Dota 2 client traffic only, I just measured a single match of 40 minutes and here are the results:

- around 37 MB downloaded
- around 11 MB uploaded

Comment: in addition there is an option to lower the network quality which could help

Comment: The console commands rate, cl_cmdrate and cl_updaterate all probably play a part in the amount of data sent.

Comment: But be aware that changing these too much _will_ force lag upon you, even if your connection is great.